# Send data to email account Java Blackberry

Tags: email, blackberry, java-me

I developed a form for Blackberry that keeps me some information, but I need that data are sent to a email address. I wonder if any of you can explain how you can do this.

Comment: You're using java, right? You put it in the title, so I added it to the tags.

Comment: Have you actually tried doing anything for yourself? I don't know much about blackberry, but people will be more inclined to help you if you make it easier for them. So get as far as you can on your own, and show us what you've done so far, and say *exactly* what your problem is. Not "I want to do X, how to do it???".

Comment: What kind of help can you possibly expect from a question with so few details? What have you tried? How did it fail? How are you trying to send email? Are you trying to use the user's BIS or BES email account? Or some other mechanism to send email? Please add many more details...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't stated what your development environment is, but if you are using Eclipse, you will find the BlackBerryMailDemo sample which should give you all the information and code you need.

e.g. on my development machine using eclipse and the BB OS 7 JDE the sample code is at:

C:\Program Files\Eclipse\eclipse 3.6.2 BlackBerry\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack7.0.0_7.0.0.33\components\samples\com\rim\samples\device

Again, if you are using eclipse, just try File->Import->BlackBerry->Import BlackBerry Samples